# Table with multiple composite attributes

Tags: sql, normalization

I have a flight table that only has composite attributes.

I have the PK, which is flight_no obviously, then I have From(city,country) and some other attributes that I similar to "From".

How can I get my table to 1NF? I know that in order to be in 1NF, there cannot be repeating groups.

Another concern is, if I create other tables from those composite attributes, I'd be left with flight_no only. Would that be OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd extract a `locations` tables that has a primary key (`location_no`, for argument's sake) and the `city` and `country` attributes.

Then, your `flights` table could be composed of its own key, `flight_no` and `to` and `from` foreign keys to the `locations` table.